# Free reporting for WPF

Tags: reporting

Is there any free reporting tool for WPF, if not then for Windows Application will do.

thanks

Comment: i used GPFReporting Tools it is Professional Tools, i think it is free. see: http://gamadev.com/?p=11175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this one

http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/

But note that is only an alpha project. Rdcl reports is safe option.